How to ask the user for permission to make a phone call for iOS in the Flutter application?
My application has code that makes a phone call, but first asks the user for permission. I need permission to be obtained directly during the call, if possible.
Future<void> _makePhoneCall() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final callPermissionStatus = await Permission.phone.request();
      if (callPermissionStatus.isGranted) {
        final String userPhone = contactPhone;
        try {
          const MethodChannel('caller').invokeMethod('makeCall', userPhone);
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: AppLocalizations.instance.translate("failedToCallTheNumber") +
                ("$contactPhone, ${e.message}"),
          );
        }
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: AppLocalizations.instance.translate("failedToCallTheNumber") +
              ("$contactPhone"),
        );
      }
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      final callPermissionStatus = await Permission.phone.request();
      if (callPermissionStatus.isGranted) {
        final String userPhone = contactPhone;
        try {
          const MethodChannel('caller')
              .invokeMethod('makeCall', userPhone);
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: AppLocalizations.instance.translate("failedToCallTheNumber") +
                (" $contactPhone, ${e.message}"),
          );
        }
      } else {
        final String userPhone = contactPhone;
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: AppLocalizations.instance.translate("failedToCallTheNumber") +
              (" $userPhone"),
        );
      }
    }
  }


This code works fine on Android, but on iOS there is no dialog box asking the user for permission. I'm using permission_handler: ^11.3.1
but in the documentation for permission_handler: ^11.3.1 I found a description for the "phone" -
/// Permission for accessing the device's phone state (Android only). static const phone = PermissionWithService._(8); 
What should I use instead of "phone" to open the phone call permission dialog for iOS?
Or should I use another library rather than permission_handler?
My flutter doctor -
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale ru-UA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

if you replace in line -
final callPermissionStatus = await Permission.phone.request();

“phone” with “contacts” - then a dialog box appears asking for permission to access contacts.

I also added these lines to the info.plist
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>needed to make phone calls</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSCallKitUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Call access permission is required to make calls.</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Permission to access contacts is required to make calls.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Permission to access the microphone is required to make calls.</string>

I'm not sure if all these lines are needed, I tried to add everything to allow a phone call to be made.

On iOS you must open a tel: url.  iOS will prompt the user to make or cancel the call

Here is the plugin for that https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller. A simple plugin to call number directly from app, without going to phone dialer. Permission request is handled by plugin.
Please follow readme.
The code lets me call.
Future<void> makeSupportCall(BuildContext context, String number) 
   async {
    try {
      String phone = preparePhone(number);
      await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(phone);
    } catch (e) {
      final text = 'error_can_not_make_a_call'.tr();
    showCommonErrorDialog(context, text);
    }
 }


I don’t have any problems specifically with a phone call, I use the same methods as library flutter_phone_direct_caller and this library works. My problem is that I don't see the phone call permission window for the user and that's why I always get FALSE when checking permission - callPermissionStatus.isGranted
